# Socket.io for Rails w/ Heroku Support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have been conflicted for a great deal of time in deciding how to update the app I am developing with notifications. In my app, users can post. I want to alert Users of new posts, just like facebook. However, given that Heroku does not support websockets and the like, deciding what to do has been tough. I DO NOT want to use pusher or pubnub as those services have outrageous prices.

In doing research, I learned about socket.io, which uses websockets if supported, then falls back on flash, or long polling to keep a connection to the server. This seems like the obvious choice for notifications b/c it will allow cross platform integration, it will be easy to implement websockets down the road, and its free.

I have been searching for a Rails 3+ Heroku supported socket.io gem, but I have read so many conflicting things that I am in great confusion. What are/is the best gem(s) to implement socket.io for Rails 3+ & Heroku?

Comment: If you want to use Socket.io on Heroku, you will have to use AJAX polling instead of websockets, since their stack doesn't support it https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

We do not support long lived connections on heroku, so unfortunately using socket.io is not supported either. I would suggest that you use AJAX pulling (as Jakub Arnold suggests) to accomplish the same thing.